# Show data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

i have function in DatabaseHandler.java

```
/**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("id_user", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("regid", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("jenis_kelamin", cursor.getString(5));
            user.put("tanggal_lahir", cursor.getString(6));
            user.put("instansi", cursor.getString(7));
            user.put("jabatan", cursor.getString(8));
            user.put("dibuat_at", cursor.getString(9));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }
```

and the question how i get data id_user, name, email,etc from database to show in MainActivity.java
please help

Comment: `HashMap<String, String> userdetails = getUserDetails()`, and then `System.out.println(userdetails.get("id_user"))`? Use TextView to show it on Activity?

Comment: show in Activity, i used HashMap<String, String> userdetails = getUserDetails(); in MainActivity but function not found?

Answer (score 0):

Create new HashMap :

```
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = getUserDetails();
```

and in your MainActivity.java just use :

```
hashMap.get(text);
```

The text field is a String which should be "id_user" , "name" , "email" , etc.

P.S : If i am not wrong, you are always taking the details from the first row..